# Firebase SDK vs Rest API

Tags: javascript, firebase, rest, web-applications, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to understand why the firebase javascript SDK is so big, and what the benefit of using the SDK.

When I started develop my webApp, I used only the SDKs, and it works really good, but then i notice that the size of the SDKs is huge! and i am using a lot of the firebase SDKs :  auth/database/firestore/functions/ and storage, so its a lot of javascript that my end users need to download to start using my app.

So I start checking out firebase rest API, and I have to say, it works pretty well.

For example, Firestore: using "webpack-bundle-analyzer" i saw that Firestore size is 1000kb, which is a lot, and for only one library.

Using the rest API I succeeded to implement all the functionally I needed with 400 lines of codes...
I implemented creating a new document, update an existing document, get documents list in a collection with or without filter (runQuery), and create/update/get subcollection of a document.

And I am trying to understand why firestore lib is so big? what am I missing?
Is it a thing of security, or solving a lot of edge cases.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you're implementing a tiny subset of what the Firebase SDK implements.

For example, you're likely only implementing the `get()` method. The SDK also implement the `onSnapshot` method, which adds *a lot* of complexity and edge cases. And there are many more such considerations, for example various data types, offline behavior, network conditions, etc.

But if your own code works for your use-case, go for it!

If you're interested in learning more on what the Firestore SDK does, I recommend checking out the [source code on Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/master/packages/firestore/src). That's also a great way to discover if your implementation misses something that may be important after all, in which case you can see if you can add an equally efficient implementation yourself.

Finally: keep in mind that the SDK is open-source. If you find something that can be done more efficiently than the SDK does it, open a bug and a PR so others can benefit from your work too.